# Building basic C++ project with boost python v1.67 and cmake on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, boost-python

This is my first attempt to write a cmake file for a production level project, I'm just trying to locate the boost python(v 1.67.0) package using cmake.

I have a very small `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
find_package(Boost 1.67.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system python37)
if(Boost_FOUND)   
    message("Boost_FOUND")
endif()
```

It works fine if I just try to find `system` but fails when I add `python37`. As per the FindBoost [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html), I need to mention it the way I have mentioned it. This is the output that I get:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2100 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.67.0

  Boost include path: /usr/include

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_python37

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

When I run `$ locate libboost_python` I get the following output:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.65.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python27.so.1.67.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python3-py37.so.1.65.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python37.so.1.67.0
```

Given this output, I assume that the package/library is present.
So, I tried to add the following line in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
```

But the error remained. What am I missing here?

Comment: You don't need `if(Boost_FOUND)`, you set `REQUIRED`.

Comment: `set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")` was added where in the file?

Comment: Right before the `find_package` line

Comment: Run `cmake` with `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON` and see which files are actually searched.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I have got a huge list of flags and their corresponding value, is there any specific that I have to check? Some contain the path that I have added in `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR`

Comment: It should be a list of files (without directories, but with extensions) which are searched for `python37` component. Check that the list contains a file which you have (`libboost_python37.so.1.67.0`). Also it should be a list of directories, where the file is searched. Check that the directories list contains your directory (`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the dev package, as there is no `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-`gnu/libboost_python27.so

Fix:

```
apt-get install libboost-python1.67-dev
```

Comment: Yes, it worked, I was using `libboost-python1.67.0` instead of one that you have mentioned